# Is it possble if I wanted to create a directories on ftp/sftp with my computer as hosts without cloud hosting

Tags: ftp, sftp

I'm just discover this sftp/ftp thing recently, is it possible that we create a directory which we can access on another computer with filezilla or other likewise application connect with my home pc as the server.

Those servers are also computers so maybe I think our home pc as server this might work?

Comment: Side note about "this sftp/ftp thing": SFTP and FTP are two separate things. FTP and FTPS are related, but FTPS is not SFTP.

Comment: OpenSSH allows for SFTP - for Windows, see [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) and for BSD/Linux search for `openssh` via it's package manager.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unless I get the question very wrong, the answer is yes. E.g. I can access my home router/server via SSH (and thus SFTP) from the outside world. Sole "yes" is not an educative answer though. This means your question is not a good question. Note this (from our [help center](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". "Is X possible?" is rarely such question. "How can I do X?" may be a good question, but you need to specify your OS, show research effort. Please see [ask].

Comment: I have this question because I'm not sure about this will work or not, wanted to confirm this method will work then only find out, and since I'm getting a "yes" from you guys, now that I'm sure that this works and I'm now figuring out  how.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do this.  The thing you should really think about is **security**.  Before that, determine your use case.  Is this to be accessed only by you, or by you and other people?  Is this only inside your home firewall or on the internet?

If this is just you, or you and people you really trust, and only inside your home firewall, then you may not need much security at all.  An ancient FTP daemon would suffice.  If this is to be accessed on the internet or by people you don't trust, then you will need a lot more security.

Security also has several parts.

#### Authentication

This is about determining who is getting at your data.  SSH (and SFTP) through keys has this strongly.  FTP and SSH through passwords is somewhat weaker, and on the internet, you should expect to be subjected to password guessing attacks.

#### Confidentiality

This basically means encryption.  If your site is internet accessed and not encrypted, people will be able to observe your traffic.  If you are also using passwords, they **will** be compromised.

#### Access Control

This means controlling what the users and read, write, and delete.  This means both that the server must defend its own integrity, preventing people modifying or deleting pieces needed for the server, and that the server may need to prevent one user from reading another users data.

#### Bugs

Must software packages have bugs.  You are best off using a package that is actively maintained, and bug fixes provided.

#### The Future

If you establish something based on not being on the internet, be very careful you don't later open it to the internet without completely reviewing the security.  If you need to export something later, you would probably be better off in this case to put it on a web server, or some other second file sharing system than trying to switch from internal-only to internet-wide.

#### Others?

I may be missing security issues.

### Conclusion

There are many packages that can do these things for you.

- SFTP might seem like a good candidate, but doesn't necessarily restrict what you can read, and *must* be properly configured.
- FTPS (or FTP) with a good server can usually give you good results, but there are many implementations, all *must* be properly configured, and I am loath to recommend one.
- Microsoft File Sharing is also an option if you aren't on the internet and mainly run MS-Windows.  (And there are some Unix/Linux implementations too, like SAMBA.)
- I'm sure there are others as well.

Comment: Thanks for the information. These information allows me to have a clearer grasp from every aspect. Initially I only wanted to have our work sync live, sharing with my friend which we are in the same project together. 
Anyway, much appreciated.

Comment: For that... you might be better off with a version control system, like CVS, Subversion, or Git.